# Erasing pen on a canvas

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a functioning drawing application for some segmentation on images. For this I have two layers, the original image and the image layer I am drawing on.

I now want to implement a method for erasing. I have implemented undo functionality, but I would also like the user to be able to select a brush "color" as to be able to erase specific parts, like the eraser in paint. I thought this would be possible by drawing with a color with opacity, but that just results in no line being drawn.

The goal for me is therefore to draw a line, that removes the pixel values in the image layer, such that I can see the underlying image

## MVP of drawing

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMenuBar, QMenu, QAction
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QImage, QPainter, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        top = 400
        left = 400
        width = 800
        height = 600

        self.setWindowTitle("MyPainter")
        self.setGeometry(top, left, width, height)

        self.image = QImage(self.size(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        self.image.fill(Qt.white)
        self.imageDraw = QImage(self.size(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        self.imageDraw.fill(Qt.transparent)

        self.drawing = False
        self.brushSize = 2
        self.brushColor = Qt.black
        self.lastPoint = QPoint()

        self.change = False
        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        changeColour = mainMenu.addMenu("changeColour")
        changeColourAction = QAction("change",self)
        changeColour.addAction(changeColourAction)
        changeColourAction.triggered.connect(self.changeColour)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drawing = True
            self.lastPoint = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() and Qt.LeftButton and self.drawing:
            painter = QPainter(self.imageDraw)
            painter.setPen(QPen(self.brushColor, self.brushSize,     Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
            painter.drawLine(self.lastPoint, event.pos())
            self.lastPoint = event.pos()
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drawing = False

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        canvasPainter = QPainter(self)
        canvasPainter.drawImage(self.rect(), self.image, self.image.rect())
        canvasPainter.drawImage(self.rect(), self.imageDraw, self.imageDraw.rect())

    def changeColour(self):
        if not self.change:
            # erase
            self.brushColor = QColor(255,255,255,0)
        else:
            self.brushColor = Qt.black
        self.change = not self.change

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

## How to erase a subset of pixels?

As in this example what color should be given to `self.brushColor` in the `changeColour` function?

### Info

The colour white is not the solution, because in reality the image at the bottom is a complex image, I therefore want to make the toplayer "see-through" again, when erasing.

Comment: What do you call complex image?

Comment: @eyllanesc just many different colours, so you cannot assume anything about the underlying image. This was just to stress the point that changes should only happen to the top layer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the [compositionMode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#CompositionMode-enum) to `QPainter::CompositionMode_Clear` and erase with [eraseRect()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#eraseRect).

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        top, left, width, height = 400, 400, 800, 600
        self.setWindowTitle("MyPainter")
        self.setGeometry(top, left, width, height)

        self.image = QtGui.QImage(self.size(), QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        self.image.fill(QtCore.Qt.white)
        self.imageDraw = QtGui.QImage(self.size(), QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        self.imageDraw.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)

        self.drawing = False
        self.brushSize = 2
        self._clear_size = 20
        self.brushColor = QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.black)
        self.lastPoint = QtCore.QPoint()

        self.change = False
        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        changeColour = mainMenu.addMenu("changeColour")
        changeColourAction = QtWidgets.QAction("change", self)
        changeColour.addAction(changeColourAction)
        changeColourAction.triggered.connect(self.changeColour)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drawing = True
            self.lastPoint = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() and QtCore.Qt.LeftButton and self.drawing:
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.imageDraw)
            painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(self.brushColor, self.brushSize, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine, QtCore.Qt.RoundCap, QtCore.Qt.RoundJoin))
            if self.change:
                r = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), self._clear_size*QtCore.QSize())
                r.moveCenter(event.pos())
                painter.save()
                painter.setCompositionMode(QtGui.QPainter.CompositionMode_Clear)
                painter.eraseRect(r)
                painter.restore()
            else:
                painter.drawLine(self.lastPoint, event.pos())
            painter.end()
            self.lastPoint = event.pos()
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drawing = False

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        canvasPainter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        canvasPainter.drawImage(self.rect(), self.image, self.image.rect())
        canvasPainter.drawImage(self.rect(), self.imageDraw, self.imageDraw.rect())

    def changeColour(self):
        self.change = not self.change
        if self.change:
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(QtCore.QSize(1, 1)*self._clear_size)
            pixmap.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(pixmap)
            painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 2))
            painter.drawRect(pixmap.rect())
            painter.end()
            cursor = QtGui.QCursor(pixmap)
            QtWidgets.QApplication.setOverrideCursor(cursor)
        else:
            QtWidgets.QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: One question and then I'll mark it as accepted :) I can easily change the size of the square, but the erase area keeps being small despite changing the clear_size?

Comment: @JTIM I find it strange, the area of the rectangle is equal to the area of the erasure. You could point out how you are implementing it, I think you are doing it incorrectly, I do not have the problem that you point out

Comment: Ahh forgot to take into account my scale factor for zooming. Thanks ;)

Comment: @JTIM you see, without a [mcve] it's hard to help :-)

Comment: hehe yeah, but the entire project was so big, and the scaling was difficult to get working (at least for me ;) ). But your code allowed me to see it should work and then it was quite clear ;)

Thx, have a nice day